# Split tensorflow dataset in dataset per class

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dataset created from one tfrecord file. This dataset contains 5 different classes.

Now I want to create batches with a fixed number of elements (8 for example) from each batch. So it should create batches of 40 elements containing 8 elements of each class.

Is this possible with tf.data?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest thing to do is (perhaps not very convenience) :

a) Prepare 5 different `TFRecords`, each ontaining elements of only one specific class.

b) Create `5` different `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` instances and hence `5` different iterators.

c) Then in the main code :

```
iterators =  [....] # Store your iterators in a list
data = list(map(lambda x : x.get_next(), iterators))
data_to_use = tf.concat(....) # Concat your data in one single batch of `40` elements.
```

## Another approach (without creating separate datasets)

a) Use only one TFRecord. But create `5` different instances of it

b) In each instance, use `tf.data.filter(predicate)` method of `tf.data` API, to filter records, which belong to one specific class. For that you will have to write a function, which can check for the class of each record.

c) Then follow step `c)` as in the previous solution.